# How to append new data in googlesheet

Tags: r, dataframe, google-sheets, dplyr, r-googlesheets

I have a below mentioned dataframe in R which I'm fetching from database using `RMySQL` on interval of 3 hours.

Query:

```
Select Form_No, Date, Name, Age from Test where Date(Date)>='2020-12-01';
```

DF:

```
Form_No      Date                  Name            Age
POS-1        2020-12-01 10:16:12   Alex            29
POS-2        2020-12-01 10:18:34   Mike            31
POS-3        2020-12-01 14:16:22   Paul            21
POS-4        2020-12-01 18:33:14   John            27
POS-5        2020-12-01 20:13:34   Cohe            45
```

It is oblivious that after every 3 hours when I run the script there are some additional entries might have created in dataframe and when I use the below-mentioned code to upload the data in googlesheet it override the previous information and update the new data.

The Problem is that for each rows there are some observations might have captured by the reviewer of the information.

The Code I am using is:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(RMySQL)
library(googlesheets)

connection<-dbConnect(MySQL(), user='User', password='Password', 
                 dbname='Db name',
                 host='host info')

Query<- paste0("Select Form_No, Date, Name, Age from Test where Date(Date)>='2020-12-01';")
DF <- dbGetQuery(connection,Query)

setwd("/home/path")
write.csv(x = DF, file = "cust_data.csv", row.names = FALSE)

as<-gs_title("TargetSheet")
gs_upload("cust_data.csv", sheet_title = "TargetSheet", overwrite = TRUE)
```

I want to keep the sequence of Form_No and every details same while uploading the new batch of information.

For Example, If I had run the query at 06:00 AM and there were five entry as shown in `DF` and all of them uploaded to google sheet, now if I run the script at 09:00 am then in my query there is possibility that along with those five entry there are some more entries.

I need to append those extra entries in google sheet now except for the five entries which are already uploaded last time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you've saved your query into a Google Sheet named "DatabaseOutput":
[image]

You can read the data with `googlesheets4::read_sheet`. To insure you get the correct column types every time, I recommend supplying the `col_types =` argument. It is very important that `read_sheet` returns the same column types as your SQL query returns. You can find more information about the argument on the [`readr`](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/cols.html) documentation page.

```
library(googledrive)
library(googlesheets4)
OldSheet <- read_sheet(drive_get("DatabaseOutput"),
                       col_types = "cTci")
OldSheet
## A tibble: 3 x 4
#  Form_No Date                Name    Age
#  <chr>   <dttm>              <chr> <dbl>
#1 POS-1   2020-12-01 10:16:12 Alex     29
#2 POS-2   2020-12-01 10:18:34 Mike     31
#3 POS-3   2020-12-01 14:16:22 Paul     21
```

Your SQL query and read from Google Sheets may disagree on exactly what time it is, so I recommend flooring the Date column with `lubridate`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
DF <- as_tibble(DF) %>% 
  mutate(Date = as_datetime(floor(seconds(Date))))
OldSheet <- OldSheet %>%
  mutate(Date = as_datetime(floor(seconds(Date))))
```

Now we can find rows which are not in the old data with `dplyr::anti_join`. If this doesn't work, double check that the column types are all the same.

```
NewRows <- anti_join(DF,OldSheet)
NewRows
## A tibble: 2 x 4
#  Form_No Date                Name    Age
#  <chr>   <dttm>              <chr> <int>
#1 POS-4   2020-12-01 18:33:14 John     27
#2 POS-5   2020-12-01 20:13:34 Cohe     45
```

Now you can append the rows to the Google Sheet with `sheet_append`:

```
sheet_append(drive_get("DatabaseOutput"),NewRows)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

***Edited to add**: I understand your question better now; you just want to append the new entries because someone else with access to your google sheet may have reviewed and made edits to previously uploaded entries. Most of my answer will remain the same as before.

Try using the googlesheets4 package instead of googlesheets.

This is what worked for me.

```
as = gs4_create("TargetSheet")
DF = as.data.frame(read.csv('cust_data.csv'))
lastRow = nrow(DF)
sheet_write(DF, ss = as, sheet = "TargetSheet")

### 3 Hours later and beyond ###

DF = as.data.frame(read.csv('cust_data.csv'))
newEntries = DF[(lastRow + 1):nrow(DF), ]
lastRow = nrow(DF)
sheet_append(ss = as, data = newEntries, sheet = "TargetSheet")
```

So for any additional entries, just keep running the last 4 lines of code every three hours. Another potential solution is basing each new query off the last known position from your previous upload, but I think my pure R solution should do just fine.